# Wordpress - Mostrar tabla de una forma para pc y de otra forma para movil

Tags: html, html5, wordpress, wordpress-plugin, wordpress-theme

tengo una instalación con wordpress y mi página inicial es una table con 3 columnas x 3 filas para mostrar un resumen de las 9 categorias.

Para ello hago una tabla, he probado bien con las tablas de wordpress o bien con el plugin "tablepress"

Mi idea es que cuando se visualize la web desde PC o tables se vea de esta manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando se acceda desde móvil  se vea de esta forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como digo me he centrado en hacerlo con plugins de wordpress, igual voy encaminado y debo buscar un theme que lo soporte?

Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes cambiar el `display` de cada elemento para que sea un bloque

- ver en pantalla completa para notar el cambio

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .restable,
  .restable tr,
  .restable td {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<table class=restable>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan=3>header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Elemento1</td>
      <td>Elemento2</td>
      <td>Elemento3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Elemento4</td>
      <td>Elemento5</td>
      <td>Elemento6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Elemento7</td>
      <td>Elemento8</td>
      <td>Elemento9</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Perfecto me funcionó a la primera. Gracias